# APK file keeps getting deleted after receiving via SHAREit

Tags: apk, shareit

My APK files are getting deleted automatically from `QieZi` folder after receiving them via SHAREit app and this is happening when I don't install them instantly.

Why this is happening? Is it Clean Master that deletes all the apps while cleaning the junks or something else?

Comment: Hard to answer without taking a direct look. Though to me it sounds like some cleaning app having gone bonkers – it could also be a device with a faulty storage or storage controller (reminds me somehow of photos disappearing just after being made, reported for several Samsung Galaxy Aces). What device do you have? Which Android version is it running? Which cleaning apps (or similar) are in use? Does it affect only `*.apk` files – only files received via ShareIt – only files on your SD card – …?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with *Clean Master* when using *Share Apps*. CleanMaster was removing regularly the received APK's.

To fix that you can:

- Uncheck the option to clean APK's in CleanMaster.
- Or uninstall it completely if you don't really need it.

Answer (score -1):

Please uncheck the last option "install" under settings in the ShareIt app. This option reads as 'delete apk files after installation'.

Answer (score -1):

Open SHAREit
And Just Uncheck "Delete After installation"
Done